# jQuery code works only if I'm logged-in to the wp-admin

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        let aboutMe = new Waypoint({
                                element: document.querySelector('.about-me'),
                                offset:'250px',
                                handler: function(direction) {
                                    setTimeout(() => {
                                        $('.about-me__img').removeClass('hidden');
                                    }, 100);
                                    setTimeout(() => {
                                        $('.about-me__img').addClass('display_decorator');
                                        $('.my-projects').removeClass('hidden');
                                    }, 500);
                                    setTimeout(() => {
                                        $('.about-me__description').removeClass('hidden');
                                    }, 1000);
                                    
                                }
                        })

    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop:true,
        margin:10,
        autoplay: true,
        avigationText: ["Dalej","Wstecz"],
        responsive:{
            0:{
                items:1
            },
            650:{
                items:2
            },
            1000:{
                items:3
            }
        }
    })
});
</script>
```

At this time I add that into Footer.php. It works but only if I'm logged-in to the wp-admin, otherwise I have an errors
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fn')
VM6552:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add JS manually to your `footer.php`, instead save it into a separate file in your theme/plugin and enqueue it with `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

If jQuery is present on your site marking "jquery" as a dependency will make sure WordPress loads your script after jQuery.

Also, make sure that your jQuery selector is indeed `jQuery()`.

```
function enqueue_custom_script(){
    wp_enqueue_script('your-script-handle', 'path-to-your-script', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
}
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "enqueue_custom_script");
```